# Is it possible to allow users to purchase simple products and nominal products (subscriptions) together with Credit Card in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.5

Is it possible to allow users to purchase simple products and nominal products (subscriptions) together with Credit Card in Magento?

Presently PayPal does not allow to purchase products and nominal products (subscriptions) together for sure. But is there any possibility that we can allow this payment using Credit Card?

If yes, then will there be any issue with the recurring payments received from customers?

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible in Magento with the recurring profiles, these are only build to work with PayPal. You could take a look at the extension from aHeadWorks, (http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments.html) maybe this will work for you (I don't have any experiance with the extension and could not find if you can checkout both normal and subscriptions products).